# chrome.tabs.executeScript|insertCss works off across through once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, styles

I add styles and scripts to a certain site in the background.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener (function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
        console.log (tabId, changeInfo, tab);
        if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' && siteUrl.test (tab.url)) {
            insertCss (tab.id, '/css/bootstrap.min.css', function () {
                insertCss (tab.id, '/css/jquery.toast.min.css', function () {
                    insertCss (tab.id, '/css/content_style.css', function () {
                        executeScript (tab.id, '/js/utils/jquery-3.3.1.js', function () {
                            executeScript (tab.id, '/js/utils/js.cookie.js', function () {
                                executeScript (tab.id, '/js/utils/jquery.toast.min.js', function () {
                                    executeScript (tab.id, '/js/utils/sweetalert2.js', function () {
                                        executeScript (tab.id, '/js/core.js', function () {
                                            executeScript (tab.id, '/js/content_script.js', function () {
                                                console.warn ('FILES INJECTION COMPLETE');
                                            });
                                        });
                                    });
                                });
                            });
                        });
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    });
```

When you go to the page everything is OK injected, but if you later update the page, the styles and scripts are inserted through the times - once you update nothing, once again, everything appears.

why is that?

If you write to manifest.json content_scripts, that also does not always work. It sometimes opens a page (does not restart) and nothing is loaded.

Comment: Add a demo extension and an URL that exhibits the problem if you can. Otherwise we can only guess. Maybe that site is AJAX-driven and uses XHR + History API to imitate navigation. Or maybe there's a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @wOxxOm i insert scripts and styles on page `https://www.linkedin.com/in/*`

Comment: See [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)